# how to refer java web project library from current project?

Tags: java, web, project

I have a web project `Web1.war` which have some jar file in its libraries (let's call it `lib.jar`). That is `Web1.war --> lib.jar`.

Then I did convert to jar file that web project: `Web1.jar`. Afterwards add the `Web1.jar` file to another java web project `Web2.war`.

How to refer that library `lib.jar` from current project (`Web2.war`) through jar file  (`Web2.war --> Web1.jar --> lib.jar`) ?

Comment: What are you using to build and manage dependencies in your projects ? Your IDE ? Or a tool like Maven ?

Comment: Hi, brother my IDE for eclipse luna. i have web project jar file. the jar have some jar library. but i could not refer to the jar library through another java web project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java only supports JAR level dependencies.  You mention having converted you 'web project' to a JAR but don't give the details of how you did this.

By default, Java uses the classpath to find dependencies.  In a 'web project' (WAR) the classpath is the `WEB-INF/classes` directory and any JARs in the `WEB-INF/lib`.

If you have classes in one 'web project' (WAR) that you need to use in another 'web project' (WAR) then you have a couple of options, both of which will involve modifying your build:

1. put shared classes are in their own jar, which you include in both 'web projects' (WARs).

or

2. unpack the first 'web project' (WAR) adding the classes (and/or libraries) to the second 'web project' (WAR).

**Update**

You cannot covert a WAR to a JAR as you have suggested in your edits.  While it's possible to create a custom archive format, a JAR cannot (and should not) contain other JARs.

Comment: hi brother thanks for answering. i have web project jar file. the jar have some jar library. but i could not refer to the jar library through another java web project

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'web project jar file' - a JAR is a JAR and cannot contain other JARs

Comment: web project jar file means i convert web application to jar file. This web application contains some jar file. so also include this jar file when web application converting  to jar. my question is how to refer that include jar from another web application?

Comment: Again, I don't know what you mean by 'covert web application to jar file'.  As I said, you cannot include JARs inside a JAR